# selenium firefox modal displays as a pop-up window, not a modal

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use Selenium to test out a form on a website that consists of multiple pages. There are modals that are suppose to appear on some of the pages based on options that are selected. Currently I'm having trouble getting Selenium to work properly with Fireforx and the modals.  Chrome acts as expected, and I haven't bothered with I.E. yet.

- When I work through the pages manually with Firefox, everything works as expected.
- When I run my Selenium script the modal displays like a Windows pop-up window, not a modal.

I'm using **driver.switchTo().alert().accept();** to handle the modals, and the first modal I encounter will close, but once I get to the next page the Selenium code is unable to find any of the elements on the page.

Here is the code I use to click a button:

```
public void pushButton(String[] values) {
    System.out.println("\t Click (" + values[1] + ")");
    setLocator(values[0], values[1]);

    try {
        clickWhenReady(locator).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find id or xpath value: " + values[1]);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setLocator(String byType, String value) {
    if(byType.toUpperCase().equals("ID")) {
        locator= By.id(value);
    } else if(byType.toUpperCase().equals("XPATH")){
        locator= By.xpath(value);
    }
}

private WebElement whenReady(By locator){
    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    return element;
}

private WebElement clickWhenReady(By locator){
    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `modals` are not `alerts` so, `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` will probably not going to buy you anything.

The real issue could be the modals take longer to fade out and blocking `Selenium` to interact with the page. Your best bet will be to try waiting for the modal to completely disappear from the dom and then try interacting with the elements. For that you can use `invisibilityOfElementLocated` of `ExpectedConditions` or similar mechanism. See [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)